# Best way to store age in database, no DOB

Tags: database, time, field, store

Ok, so I need to store ages in a database. There are no DOBs because the data set is animals with an age estimate. The ages can be days, weeks, months or years. What is the best way to store this? We have 1 year, or .5 year (6 months), or 9/52=.17307... (for 9 weeks), and that is how it is stored now. So for anything under 1 year, the entry person needs to calculate the age in this way. Trying to figure out a better way than this mess. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because you store it one way in the db doesn't mean that the app has to use that same format for data entry.  Store it internally in days, and in the app allow the user to enter whatever value is appropriate, and convert it when you store it.

Comment: Why can't you estimate the date of birth?

Comment: Neil has a good point

Comment: @Jason - I will probably have the user input one thing, and store it in the database differently. I supposed it should be stored as a decimal so I can convert it back to what it should be (.17307... is 9 weeks)?

Comment: @Neil - The user would have to estimate the DOB, & another issue is that at the time the user obtains this information, it could be outdated already. For example, the data could say animal is 9 wks old, & user is entering today, but the initial exam date of this animal was 2 months ago. We want to make sure we capture the 9 wks old, not 2 mos 9 wks (or whatever). The source is also messy, very inconsistent, so the likelihood of user error is high. We have to rely on them reading the estimated age which is listed in the animal's description (aka the 9 weeks old). Hope that cleared it up a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not store it in the most granular form, say days, and then you can convert it to weeks, months, years etc.

Comment: I think this would work rather cleanly, no decimals, just days. Thanks!